# How to: concurrent cURL downloads?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, bash-scripting

How can we use curl to download several files concurrently? Even if we need to spawn multiple curl processes, how can I do it from command line or shell function? For example:

```
$ multiCurl <download 1> <download 2> <download 3>

multiCurl () {
  curl <download 1>
  curl <download 2>
  curl <download 3>
}
```

or

```
for link in $(cat download.list); do
  curl <link 1>
  curl <link 2>
  curl <link 3>
  curl <link 4>
done
```

Comment: Found some more options here https://serverfault.com/questions/456490/execute-curl-requests-in-parallel-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use command `parallel` to download multiple files concurrently.

Here I assume you reserve original file name

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

funcDownloadOperation(){
    link="${1:-}"
    curl -fsSL -O "${link}"
    if [[ -s "${link##*/}" ]]; then
        echo "file ${link##*/} download successfully!"
    else
        echo "fail to download link ${link}"
    fi
}

export -f funcDownloadOperation
cat download.list | parallel -k -j 0 funcDownloadOperation
```

You need to install utility `parallel` manually in your linux system.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `&` at the end of each command to make it execute in the background:

```
curl <link 1>&
```

After it all depend if in addition you want to know when these commands end and what their return code is. If so, you wan try something like:

```
set -a pids # Array of the process ids of background commands
for url in $whatever_the_list_of_urls 
do
    curl $url&  # start CURL in background
    pids[${#pids[*]}]=$! # remember PID 
done

# all started, now wait for them
for pid in ${pids[*]}
do
    wait $pid 
    print "Sensed end of $pid, rc:=$?"
done
```